# Read Table of content with equations Microsoft Word Document File

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-word

I had a requirement, in which I want to  import Summation with formula from word table to website, using C#.

So for this I am using this coding :

```
   protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //fuWordFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(fuWordFile.FileName));
    object filename = Server.MapPath(fuWordFile.FileName);
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationClass AC = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationClass();
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document doc = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document();
    object readOnly = false;
    object isVisible = true;
    object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
    try
    {
        doc = AC.Documents.Open(ref filename, ref missing, ref readOnly, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref isVisible);
        TextBox1.Text = doc.Content.Text;

        foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Table tb in doc.Tables)
        {
            for (int row = 1; row <= tb.Rows.Count; row++)
            {

                var cell = tb.Cell(row, 1);
                var cell2 = tb.Cell(row, 2);
                var cell3 = tb.Cell(row, 3);
                var cell4 = tb.Cell(row, 4);
                var cell5 = tb.Cell(row, 5);
                var cell6 = tb.Cell(row, 6);
                var text = cell.Range.Text;
                var text2 = cell2.Range.Text;
                var text3 = cell3.Range.Text;
                var text4 = cell4.Range.Text;
                var text5 = cell5.Range.Text;
                var text6 = cell6.Range.Text;
                // text now contains the content of the cell.
                string encoded11 = System.Uri.UnescapeDataString(text2);
                string encoded = EncodeNonAsciiCharacters(text2);
                Console.WriteLine(encoded);

                string decoded = DecodeEncodedNonAsciiCharacters(encoded);
                Console.WriteLine(decoded);
            }
        }

        AC.Documents.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }

}
```

Also attached the screen shot
[I want to enter the equations from the word table to website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZExG.png)

Comment: Which version of Word is this and what tool was used to create the equations?

Comment: Side note: running Office application not supported in headless server environment (i.e. APS.Net); please avoid pokemon exception handling (there is no need to show empty try/catch in sample code...)

Comment: We are using ms word 2007 and the equations with formula are written on the tables.

Comment: Word 2007 I understand. There is a tool built into Word for creating equations, but there are also professional, licensed products that are used by many people to create equations in Word. It's important to know EXACTLY how the equations were generated. In most cases they are not "simple text" so the approach you're trying to use cannot work. But without knowing which technology is supporting them, we cannot help you further...